# IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE support Drools?

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I wrote drl file in IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE, but don't feel any support. Do you know the reason?

Comment: There is a plugin for 12: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/11/intellij-idea-12-eap-122813-with-vaadin-and-drools-support/ Perhaps it works in v13 as well: just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `*.drl` files are assigned to the drools plugin.

Open *Settings* -> *File Types* -> *Recognized File Types*: select *Drools files* and in *Registered Patterns* add *`.drl`.

Comment: What's name which the drools plugin? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I found a a detailed solution: http://planet.jboss.org/post/add_jboss_drools_support_in_intellij_idea_leif_hanack.